# Letsencrypt auto-renewal is failing with a 409 (Conflict)

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs, lets-encrypt

I set up the letsencrypt extension in Azure Portal several months ago by following this: https://github.com/sjkp/letsencrypt-siteextension/wiki/How-to-install

Everything worked fine. But now when it's trying to renew the cert, I see the logs in Web Jobs showing that it failed. The first error was due to:

```
The Lets Encrypt ACME server was probably unable to reach 'http://<site>/.well-known/acme-challenge/<stuff>'
```

I found this post: https://blog.nicholasrogoff.com/2017/02/21/lets-encrypt-extension-for-azure-app-services/

Then added some settings that I was missing. And now I'm getting a 409 (Conflict) error.

What else do I need to check?

Comment: do you have renewed copy of cert?

Comment: Check this link: https://gooroo.io/GoorooTHINK/Article/16420/Lets-Encrypt-Azure-Web-Apps-the-Free-and-Easy-Way/21872#.XRTA_ugzbIU

Comment: I finally figured it out. It was due to an incorrect setting in Azure.

Comment: So you might share which setting was incorrect?

Comment: @NJB - I was wondering if you can share what setting you fixed in Azure since I'm now experiencing a similar issue. Thanks!

Comment: @ajawad987 - I ran into another issue after this error, so I ended up just removing the SSL cert and starting it over from scratch. There was an updated version so things got out of sync. After I removed the cert, updated the letsencrypt extension, then followed the directions on setting it up again, it resolved itself.

Comment: @The-First-Tiger - Sorry, I thought I posted a response, but I guess it didn't save.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem for one of my azure functions.
The error actually comes from Kudu that refuses editing when the site it is "run from package"

The solution was simply to set **WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE** to **0** in application settings.